# Cannot require config module 3 directories away in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this line `const config = require(".../config");` in user.controller.js.
This is my directory structure:
[image: directory structure]

Comment: This import isn't working from any files in the controllers, middleware, models, and routes files.

Comment: It's not one dot per directory, you want `../../config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

const config = require ("../../config")